# Alternative to using conditionals in Clojure functions so I can return a value

Tags: clojure, return, conditional-statements

I'm just starting out with clojure and I'm doing a project for fun. In the below function I'm just trying to display some blog posts (with some options). With the "as" option, I want to give the client code the ability to choose between vector `[]` and map `{}`. I had this working when I only had `(into [] results)`, but as soon as I put the `(when)` statement in, it stopped working. I guess `(when)` just returns `nil` because it's like an implicit `(do)`. It's obvious to me now that using `(when)` at the end like this is the wrong way to end a function you expect to return a value. How do I get this to work?

```
(ns yf.models.post
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as sql]
            [clojure.string :as str])
  (:use [yf.models.helpers :only [date-format]]))


(defn all [& {:keys [order limit roots-only as]}]
  (sql/with-connection (System/getenv "DATABASE_URL")
    (sql/with-query-results results
      [(str 
        "SELECT
          id,
          body,"
          (date-format "created") ","
          (date-format "modified")
        "FROM post a"
        (when (true? roots-only)
          " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT child_id from post_map b
                          WHERE a.id=b.child_id) ")
        (when (and
                (string? (order :column))
                (string? (order :dir))
                (or 
                  (= (:dir order) "asc")
                  (= (:dir order) "desc")))
          (str " ORDER BY a." (:column order) " " (:dir order)))
        (when (and
                (instance? Number limit)
                (pos? limit))
          (str " LIMIT " limit)))]
      (when (and                     ;this is where the problem is
              (string? as)
              (not (str/blank? as)))
        (when (= as "vector")
          (into [] results))
        (when (= as "map")
          (into {} results))))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't that `(when)` always returns `nil`--it doesn't always return `nil`; it returns whatever is last in the collection of expressions. `(when)` is a macro that uses '`(if)` and `(do)` and that's exactly what `(do)` does: executes a list of expressions and returns the value of the last one in the collection.

I tried the `(case)` macro instead and it works:

```
...
(case as
  "vector" (into [] results)
  "map" (into {} results))
```

Or, better (thanks kotarak):

```
(into (empty as) results)
```

where `as` is like `vector` (as opposed to `"vector"`, I think)

Comment: you answered your own question? Hit edit and repost your question :P

Comment: @PrototypeStark I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: nevermind, I just asked why you answered your own question @tjb1982

Comment: @PrototypeStark: I know. Sorry. It's because the answer came to me a few minutes after I submitted it

Comment: Instead of making `as` a string make it the prototype itself: `(into (empty as) results)`. And the `case` is gone.